# Mathematica implementation of Earth Movers Distance?

Tags: programming, equation-solving, matrix

Has anyone implemented in *Mathematica* the [Earth Mover's Distance (EMD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance)? A concept dating back to Monge 1871, used to compare histograms and images, e.g., the CIEDE2000 Color Difference algorithm. Yossi Rubner's C implementation can be found here:

- [Header file](http://ai.stanford.edu/~rubner/emd/emd.h)
- [C source](http://ai.stanford.edu/~rubner/emd/emd.c)

Computation of EMD is more involved than Euclidean metric. EMD is a linear constrained optimization problem, and so can be handled presumably via *Mathematica*'s Linear Programming functionality. Although there's typically additional normalization stage, e.g.. found [here](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~ofirpele/FastEMD/code/).

Comment: Couldn't you just link to the compiled code you refer to?

Comment: A related demonstration at [Monge-Kantorovich Problem](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MongeKantorovichTransportationProblem/)

Comment: @SCdeV, 2many papers 2read. There's the Wavelet dual EMD approximation, there's Quadratic Chi metrics, there's a whole book called Dictionary of Distances. And then there's the ultrametric paradise, in sparse data regimes where all triangles are isoceles w/ small base.

Comment: If you mangle my name the @-calling mechanism won't notify me. I just happened to chance by now. My remark was not about reading stuff but about linking to the C code.

Comment: @Sjoerd, my bad on name mangling... the .h and .c code are linked in my original question. ??

Comment: I meant linking **Mathematica** (not this question) to the C code. There are several mechanisms to do this.

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer a native MMA implementation. Do you think offering bounty would do it or too involved?

Answer (score 7):

In *Mathematica 9*, it is already implemented under `ImageDistance`.

See [Similarity Graph of Images Using Earth Mover Distance](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/advanced-image-processing-with-large-image-support/similarity-graph-of-images-using-earth-mover-dista.html).

Comment: Well this would be one easy bounty...

Comment: Isn't this only for 2D and 3D cases?