# Are there any functions that can determine the disorder between two lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

```
dj11 = {1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 10, 15, 30, 7, 14, 21, 42, 35, 70, 105, 210, 
11, 22, 33, 66, 55, 110, 165, 330, 77, 154, 231, 462, 385, 770, 
1155, 2310};

dj12=Sort[dj11]  

(* {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 21, 22, 30, 33, 35, 42, 55, 66,
70, 77, 105, 110, 154, 165, 210, 231, 330, 385, 462, 770, 1155, 2310} *)
```

I need to see if there is any way to determine the amount of disorder between the two lists dj11 and dj12 (i.e., how much complexity has been removed).

**Motivation** I am exploring the changes in complexity for the square-free numbers as we step through the integers. *Square-free numbers* are just the divisors of a primorial. Example *(top view)*: $dj11 = \text{Join}(dj7, dj7 * p_{11})$.

Comment: I can only see *one* list.

Comment: what's the meaning the amount of disorder? something like `Inversions` in the Combinatorica`?

Comment: You can give a try with `HammingDistance[dj11,Union[dj11]]`...

Comment: There is e.g. `Signature[dj11]`, but  more appropriate for your task would be: `NeedlemanWunschSimilarity[ dj11, Sort@dj11]`, `SmithWatermanSimilarity[ dj11, Sort@dj11]` , `DamerauLevenshteinDistance[ dj11, Sort@dj11]`.

Comment: `Entropy` is sometimes used as a measure of order.

Comment: @PlatoManiac, HammingDistance looks promising.

Comment: In general, have a look [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/DistanceAndSimilarityMeasures.html) and [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/SequenceAlignmentAndComparison.html)

Comment: @Artes, all but Signature might do it.  More analysis is required.

Comment: @bills, Entropy returns 1 for ordered and -1 for disordered.  I already know I have a lot of disorder. The OP is just a small example of my data.

Comment: How about saying what your *real problem* is?

Comment: @SimonWoods, thanks for the links.

Comment: @FredKline Entropy is always nonnegative. Perhaps you meant to say that `Signature` returns +1 or -1.

Comment: @HyperGroups, I'll read up on Inversions in my Combinatorica book.

Comment: @FredKline I think You are asking for some general exposition of the subject and it needs more elaborated answer than I can add at the moment. On the other hand signature is a hint to permutations, in other words some of the another functions I mentioned, count the number of transpositions, which is closely related.

Comment: @J.M., I'm attempting to see if there can be some method to show the increasing complexity of square-free numbers as we move up the number line.

Comment: @Aky, you are right, it was Signature. Entropy returns the log of number of items in the list.

Comment: @FredKline, `Entropy` will return the log of the number of items in the list if the list has all unique items (as in your example) but not generally.

Comment: You might want to take a look at `EditDistance` - it's mentioned in the reference Simon pointed you to.

Comment: @Aky, thanks. I will never have duplicates, so Entropy is out. But I will look at EditDistance.

Comment: Are you using `Union` for a reason or would `Sort` be equivalent? If there are no duplicates, a one-to-one mapping would be possible.

Comment: @YvesKlett, I use Union because I can easily describe it in LaTex.

Comment: `Union` in *Mathematica* implies you are after potentially duplicate entries - would recommend you edit your question (`Union`-> `Sort`) to remove ambiguities.

Comment: Would the Earth Mover Distance referred to in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3919/mma-implementation-of-earth-movers-distance) be useful?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, I used to own that book. For my research, I want to trend the complexity changes as we step through the number line. I know the result at $\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**:

`PearsonCorrelationTest` is appropriate  for checking the amount of variance in common between the original and the ordered lists.

```
dj11 = {1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 10, 15, 30, 7, 14, 21, 42, 35, 70, 105, 210, 
11, 22, 33, 66, 55, 110, 165, 330, 77, 154, 231, 462, 385, 770, 1155, 2310};

dj12 = Ordering[dj11];

PearsonCorrelationTest[dj12, Range[Length[dj12]], "TestDataTable"]
```

[image: Pearson]

```
0.923387^2
```

> 0.852644

There is an 85% overlap in the variance shared by the order of the elements in dj12 and the range 1...n.

```
ListPlot[{dj12, Range[Length[dj12]]}, AxesLabel -> {"Range[]", "dj12"}, BaseStyle -> 18]
```

[image]

Comment: @FredKline.  Actually, `Correlation` doesn't do just what I was looking for.  I switched to `PearsonCorrelationTest`.

Comment: What happens when dj11 and dj12 are compared? Can Correlation do anything when the numbers are identical, but in different positions?

Comment: `SpearmanRankTest`, which assumes ordinal rather than interval data, returns the same result as the Pearson test.